# Rearrange columns of a pandas dataframe in a specific way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have below dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
Dat = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 'b' : ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y'], 'val' : [1,12,-3,23]})
```

Now I want to shape above dataframe and rearrange as below

```
pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,1,0,0], 'B' : [0,0,1,1], 'X' : [1,0,1,0], 'Y' : [0,1,0,1], 'val' : [1,12,-3,23]})
```

Basically, values of columns `a & b` in original dataframe are put as column in the new dataframe and fill the corresponding cells of the new dataframe using `1/0`.

Is there any direct function/method available in python to accomplice the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) operation:

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['a', 'b'], prefix='', prefix_sep='').astype(int)
```

---

```
   val  A  B  X  Y
0    1  1  0  1  0
1   12  1  0  0  1
2   -3  0  1  1  0
3   23  0  1  0  1
```